# Significance of return keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, return

I am new to javascript, don't mind if this question seems silly. What is the significance of return keyword in third last line of code when we can omit this?

```
function showName (firstName, lastName) {
    var nameIntro = "Your name is ";
    function makeFullName () 
    {       
        alert( nameIntro + firstName + " " + lastName);   
    }

    return makeFullName(); // here we can omit "return" then also it is functioning same
}
showName ("Michael", "Jackson");
```

Comment: `return undefined` can always be omitted - a function that doesn't explicitly `return` (like your `makeFullName`) will return `undefined` implicitly.

Comment: Where did you get this code? The tutorial I found with almost identical code (http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/) has `makeFullName()` return a string instead of alerting the text, which makes more sense.

Comment: @Juhana: Yes, i copied from that site only, i was trying on jsfiddle just for knowing the output.

Comment: Did you also add the alert? Because that's not in the original.

Comment: Yes i added it myself, but that was not the point.See Brian Glaz's answer. I was asking in that context.

Comment: You changed the code so much that the return keyword wasn't needed *any more*. It *is* needed *in the original code* and can't be omitted.

Comment: Sorry Juhana, I didn't know that that could make difference. That's why i did. Will take care of that from onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you do not need `return` because your function does not produce any object or value, it simply does something. (it alerts the string)

Let's say, however, that you wanted to save the value of the nameIntro string and use it later. Your function could be modified to return the value, which could be saved as a variable. The following code will produce the same results, but makes use of `return`:

```
function showName (firstName, lastName) {
    var nameIntro = "Your name is ";
    function makeFullName () 
    {       
        return nameIntro + firstName + " " + lastName;   
    }

    return makeFullName();
}
var nameString = showName("Michael", "Jackson");
alert(nameString);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that enforces a return in that place, remove it and live your life in peace. :)

```
makeFullName()
```

instead of

```
return makeFullName()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function showName (firstName, lastName) {
  var intro = 'Your name is';
  return intro + ' ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName;
}

alert(showName("Michael", "Jackson"));
```