# Could anyone please explain to me what is the difference between return vs alert function in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please explain the difference between return vs alert function in my code. When I run this code on JS.bin, it is giving me the same output. But I am not able to understand the use of return keyword?

```js
function Random () {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)+ 1;
  return randomNumber;
}
alert(Random());
```

```js
function Random () {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)+ 1;
  alert(randomNumber);
}
Random();
```

Comment: You are using alert in both examples

Comment: Return means the function call itself is treated like a variable in whatever expression uses it.

Comment: If you are asking this question you don't understand something quite basic. Both of your snippets are doing the same thing. The difference being that in the first snippet you're returning a value from a function then calling the alert function on it. In the second snipped you're calling that within the function and not returning a value. But that is obvious, so I suggest you learn programming basics. Here is a reference to the return keyword: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Since we are getting the same output, why programmers prefer to use return function?

Comment: return is an operator, not a function. The point of using return is that it allows you to abstract an idea to a function. Then the only piece of code you need to read is `alert(Random());` then you already know what the function does by its name, there's no need to look it up. Plus by using "return" you can decide whether you're going to output it or not, so you can use it in other calculations, or use a different manner of output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Significance of return keyword in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610872/significance-of-return-keyword-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` tells whatever initiated the function that function is now over and the result is whatever the result is. However that result exists only in the internals of your computer and is not shown to the user unless you present it within an `alert`.

In your example, both functions appear to do the same thing because both in fact use `alert`. The only difference is that one has the alert as part of the function and the other does not.

When run, your first function returns a value, which you then alert the user to independent of the function, whereas the other alerts the user to your result as part of the function.